# Android-Annotations Can I trigger onViewChanged manually to pick up on newly added views to the layout

Tags: android, android-annotations

I have a listview that I add a header to, the header has a bunch of views contained in it so it would make things alot easier if I can reference these views by @ViewById in my class, the problem is they are all null as the method

```
@Override
public void onViewChanged(HasViews hasViews) { }
```

fires before I can add the header the listview thus not finding them in the layout.

So basically I want to force AA to re look up all the @ViewById views.

Comment: post some code with the question. it would help with the context of your problem. for example, if you reference your header wrong, you will get null views

Comment: It's really a specific question to android-annotations, I can add the header and reference the views manually with findViewById

Comment: What if you override `onPostResume()` and access the views when the header is already rendered? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostResume()

Comment: *possibly related* if anyone can help. The onViewChanged in the generated InflatedRow_ class is not triggered. the mChildren says all children are null. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538117/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-add-androidannotation-eviewgroups-instead-of-usin