# Is it possible to dynamically add AndroidAnnotation @EViewGroups instead of using the traditional inflate directly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate, android-annotations

I'm trying to use Android Annotations and dynamically add layout components when my **createNewRow** button is clicked. The app runs and displays the default rows defined in **activity_main.xml** and, after clicking **createNewButton** I see children attached to my **dynamicTable** in the debugger but the new children are not displayed. Here is my main activity XML:

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/inflateLayout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              tools:context="net.richardriley.inflate.app.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createNewRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/newRowButton"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dynamicTable">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So simply a linear layout with a button and then a table container. Clicking **createNewRow** should add a new **InflatedRow**. Here is the XML for the row I want to dynamically add:

**inflatedrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inflatedRowTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/inflatedRowLabel"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/inflatedRowButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/defaultNewRowText"
            />

</merge>
```

Using AA my subclass for a tableRow is

**InflatedRow.java**

```
package net.richardriley.inflate.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

/**
 * inflate : Created by rgr on 20/03/14.
 */
@EViewGroup(R.layout.inflatedrow)
public class InflatedRow extends TableRow {

    @ViewById
    Button inflatedRowButton;

    @ViewById
    TextView inflatedRowTextView;

    public InflatedRow(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

and finally my main activity java itself:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package net.richardriley.inflate.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.android.BasicLogcatConfigurator.configureDefaultContext;

@OptionsMenu(R.menu.main)
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static {
        configureDefaultContext();
        log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @ViewById
    LinearLayout inflateLayout;

    @ViewById
    TableLayout dynamicTable;

    public MainActivity() {
    }

    protected static Logger log;

    @Click
    void createNewRow() {
        log.info("clicked");
        InflatedRow_ inflatedRow=new InflatedRow_(this);
        dynamicTable.addView(inflatedRow,0);
        /*LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatedrow,null);
        dynamicTable.addView(view);*/
    }

    @OptionsItem
    void openSettingsSelected(){
        log.info("Hello");
    }

}
```

In **createNewRow** if I use the inflater service directly it works.

What am I missing?

many thanks.

Comment: Update #1 : It seems I need to call the shadow/generated class .build() method as opposed to just constructing it. e.g instead of 'View inflatedRow= new InflatedRow_(this);' I use 'View inflatedRow=InflatedRow_.build(this);'. I need to scour the docs to see why I missed this then I'll update the OP. But progress!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the annotated class when you're inflating the view and make sure you're calling the build method that inflates it.

```
@Click
void createNewRow() {
    log.info("clicked");
    InflatedRow inflatedRow = new InflatedRow_.build(this);
    dynamicTable.addView(inflatedRow,0);

}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. The key is to use the generated class with the underline at the end and the build method.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but .build() is static > no new operator. 'InflatedRow inflatedRow = InflatedRow_.build(this);'

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'View inflatedRow= new InflatedRow_(this);' I use 'View inflatedRow=InflatedRow_.build(this);'. This is documented for custom controls and I needed to do it for a merged control group too. So mea culpa to a degree!

```
@Click
    void createNewRow() {
        log.info("clicked");
        InflatedRow_ inflatedRow=InflatedRow_.build(this);
        dynamicTable.addView(inflatedRow,0);
    }
```

Alternatively (and no idea if this would continue to be supported:

```
@Click
    void createNewRow() {
        log.info("clicked");
        /*View inflatedRow = InflatedRow_.build(this);*/
        InflatedRow_ inflatedRow = new InflatedRow_(this);
        inflatedRow.onFinishInflate();
        dynamicTable.addView(inflatedRow, 0);

    }
```